# Finding the net charge from $E=c(1-e^{-\alpha r})/ r^2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

> An electric charge distribution produces an electric field
>   $$E=c(1-e^{-\alpha r})\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}\tag{1}$$
>   where c and $\alpha$ are constants. Find the net charge within the radius $r=1/\alpha$

I figured this problem was just a straight forward exercise of Gauss's Law so I did
$$Q=\epsilon_0\int E\cdot dA = \epsilon_0 \int_0^{1/\alpha}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}E r^2 sin(\theta )drd\theta d\phi\tag{2}$$
This gets you that $Q=\frac{4 \pi c}{\alpha e}$.

However, this problem comes from a problem book which supplies the solutions where they have used Gauss's law as 
$$\int_{S_0} E\cdotp dS = 4\pi Q\tag{3}$$
So that $Q=c(1-e^{-1})$

I was wondering where my mistake was in applying Gauss's law and how they have the $4\pi$ in front of the Q.

Comment: Is the last integral you've written not missing the $\epsilon_0$?

Comment: I think it is, but that is how the book has it.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the removed comments I found that the error I made was due to me taking a volume integral rather then the surface integral. Taking the surface integral (2) becomes
$$Q=\epsilon_0 E(r=\frac{1}{\alpha} )\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} sin(\theta )d\theta d\phi\tag{2} = 4 \pi \epsilon_0 c(1-e^{-1})$$

The additional factor of $4 \pi \epsilon_0$ comes from a different choice of units so we have the equivalent solution as that of the book.